# User-defined variables set by parameters

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

The SQL is am using is:

```
SET @person1_id = ?;
SET @person2_id = ?;
SET @safety_factor = ?;
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE person1 = @person1_id
AND person2 = @person2_id
AND safety_factor = @safety_factor;
```

That's not the exact code, but shows what i'm trying to do

The way I then input parameters is

```
Statement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(*script*)
stmt.setLong(1, person1.id)
stmt.setLong(2, person2.id)
stmt.setBigDecimal(3, safetyFactor)
```

I'm using variables in the sql because the values are used repeatedly throughout the script, and I don't want to have to input the same value multiple times as different parameters.

This gives me an error,

> Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Invalid value
>   "2" for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-195]

I imagine this is to do with the script being treated as four separate statements, but I don't know how to execute them seperately and have the variables work between statements.

Comment: What is "stmt".  I am guessing from your error message that the problem is that stmt has an array of some kind, which has not been initialised with the correct number of elements.

Comment: Updated to explain what stmt is. There's no arrays used, the only parameters are the ones shown in the example sql above

Comment: I'm guessing here that the problem is internal to the prepareStatement(*script*).  Your sql's first line (prior to first ";") contains only one parameter.  I guess therefore that this only allows you to subsequently add one parameter.  You need your first sql statement to use all three parameters.

Comment: Can you not use a temporary table and have your first statement as being INSERT INTO tmpTable VALUES(x, y, z), and then access the variables from there?  Better still would be to create a stored procedure, particularly if you have multiple statements to execute.

Comment: Why not just dispense with the first three lines, and have `SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE person1 = ?
AND person2 = ?
AND safety_factor = ?;` for the SQL?

Comment: The variables are used multiple times in the select part of the query (the one above is considerably simplified), so I would have to specify each value multiple times. While that is a valid solution, I feel like the method above is cleaner and easier to use, and would like to try and make it work before resorting to specifying each value multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2 cannot handle a parameterised query with multiple sql statements. When setting a parameter, it will only look as far as the first semicolon, meaning that it only sees 1 parameter to be set.

Since user-defined variables are [session scoped](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set__), we can set the variables in a separate statement.

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SET @person1_id = ?")
statement.setLong(1, person1.id)
statement.execute()

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SET @person2_id = ?")
statement.setLong(1, person2.id)
statement.execute()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it this will help, but in this case I usually use another syntax (for SQL Server):

```
declare @person1_id long
declare @person2_id long
declare @safety_factor int

SELECT @person1_id=?, @person2_id=?, @safety_factor=?

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE person1 = @person1_id
AND person2 = @person2_id
AND safety_factor = @safety_factor;
```

Comment: Sadly H2 doesn't have anything similar to "declare", and I can't see a way to convert that syntax to be valid H2 SQL